# Расположение блоков в CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть 4 блока и анимация посередине, 2 блока справа от анимации и 2 слева. Нужно, чтобы эти блоки были друг под другом. Один сверху, другой снизу и справа также, а анимация посередине. но почему-то у меня только под одному блоку получается с каждой стороны Как сделать 4 блока?

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --time: 24;
}

.div-txt p.label {
  color: #0065de;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
  /*  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);*/
}

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s);
}

.div-txt {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    color: #ED0400;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div-img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
                            <div class="div-txt">
                                <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Connect</p>
                                <p>device on the shoulders, <br>turn on it and connect application <br>with device.</p>

                                <img src="img/calibrate.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Calibrate</p>
                                <p>Aset up calibration to <br>help device remember your upright <br>and slouch positions.</p>
                            </div>
                              <div class="div-img">
                                <img src="img/mockups/2.png" title="Image 1">
                                <img src="img/mockups/3.png" title="Image 2">
                                <img src="img/mockups/5.png" title="Image 3">
                                <img src="img/mockups/6.png" title="Image 4">
                                <img src="img/mockups/7.png" title="Image 5">
                                <img src="img/mockups/8.png" title="Image 6">
                                <img src="img/mockups/9.png" title="Image 7">
                                <img src="img/mockups/10.png" title="Image 8">
                              </div>
                            <div class="div-txt">
                                <img src="img/train.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="color: #0065de; margin-top: 10px;">Train</p>
                                <p>posture anytime you want, <br>set up daily goal to improve gradually <br>your posture.</p>
                                <img src="img/analyze.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
                                <p class="label" style="margin-top: 15px;">Analyze</p>
                                <p>Statistics let you track and analyze <br>the progress you’ve made from first <br>training to the last.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Здесь картинки 600 на 600px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед тем, как что-либо менять, внимательно посмотрите на изменения в коде, проанализируйте и, только когда всё будет понятно, продолжайте. *"Спешите медленно"* ©

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --time: 24;
}

.div-txt {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 5px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.div-txt img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.div-txt p.label {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #0065de;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(1) .div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(1) .div-txt:nth-child(2) p.label {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(3) .div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(3) .div-txt:nth-child(2) p.label {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
  /* background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153, 153, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  */
}

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s);
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    color: #ED5F8A;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .div-img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-wrap-txt">
    <div class="div-txt">
      <img src="img/ect.svg">
      <p class="label">Connect</p>
      <p>the shoulders, <br>turn on it and connect application <br>with device.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-txt">
      <img src="img/svgfor.svg">
      <p class="label">Calibrate</p>
      <p>set up calibration to <br>help device remember your upright <br>and slouch positions.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=998" title="Image 1">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=535" title="Image 2">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=593" title="Image 3">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=219" title="Image 4">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=841" title="Image 5">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=1011" title="Image 6">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=1016" title="Image 7">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=976" title="Image 8">
  </div>
  <div class="div-wrap-txt">
    <div class="div-txt">
      <img src="img/train.svg">
      <p class="label">Train</p>
      <p>osture anytime you want, <br>set up daily goal to improve gradually <br>your posture.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-txt">
      <img src="img/yze.svg">
      <p class="label">Analyze</p>
      <p>et you track and analyze the <br>progress you’ve made from first <br>training to the last.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, а можно спросить еще, каким образом можно подвинуть эти блоки ближе к анимации, то есть чтобы они были посередине от левого края страницы до анимации и справа так же? UPD: когда смотрю как это отображается через телефон, то справа остается большое пространство, как его убрать можно?

Comment: @UModeL хорошие ответы всегда приятно плюсовать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо. Подписался на вашу ленту на ruSO ))